# WordPress Multisite Admin links not updating/missing domain

Tags: wordpress, multisite

This didn't happen before, but now when new sites in multisite are created, or if I rename a test site, the links within the WordPress site admin aren't updating correctly.

If I change the subdomain to a test site, the admin link doesn't update.

When I create a new site, the link ends up as

```
https://wp-admin
```

which doesn't work obviously.

When I go to the site settings, the urls are correct.

Anyone seen this before? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be missing the domain in the HTTPS plugin settings.